# Script to Add and mount Hard disk in a Vm from powershell host

Tags: windows, vmware, powercli

I have a Powercli script to add and mount harddisk in a VM, If I am calling the script from same Powershell host to add disk in the same powershell host VM - Its working But when I am calling the script for Other VMs its giving Error.Can we Mount the disk from other VM?

***The error is:*** New-HardDisk : The term 'New-HardDisk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Consider specifying whether it is VMWare/VirtualBox/other and adding screenshots of what works and what doesn't

Answer (score 0):

New-HardDisk is a PowerCLI cmdlet, so if you're trying to run that on a remote system you'll need to make sure that system has the VMware.PowerCLI modules available to it.

Ideally, you should be running the New-HardDisk cmdlet from your PowerShell host and then performing the disk mounting commands on the destination VM via something like Invoke-VMScript or PowerShell remoting.

Comment: Yes i Tried the same method but for Mounting, Invoke-VMScript is not working. This is the set of commands, I tried  every waybut its giving error. 
  New-HardDisk -VM $Vmname -Datastore $datastore -CapacityGB $diskSize -Persistence $diskMode -DiskType $diskType -StorageFormat $thinProvisioning
Get-Disk |

Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' |

Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru |

New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize |

Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "disk" -Confirm:$false